# Misplaced list elements due to CSS in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, list, overflow

I have a list of names which is rendered inside `<ul>`. I am applied some CSS code but facing some browser specific issues.

- **Chrome** : List element is getting displaced by 1 row.
- **Firefox** : All list items collapsing to one item.

Code snippet ([JS bin editor](http://jsbin.com/ediloh/4/edit))

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
<ul class='list'>
  <li> <div class='rel'> 
          <div class='abs'> item 1 </div>
  </div> </li>

  ... More items similar to above one
```

Css

```
#container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width: 200px
}

.list {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.rel {
  position: relative;
}

div.abs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

I want to know the reason of this misbehavior in both the browsers. Have I written wrong CSS ?

Update: With in `<div class='abs'>` I have a lot of code which I have not added here as it is not necessary and the content of abs div is positioned with respect to its parent i.e. `<div class='rel'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed the

```
div.abs {
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
}
```

This positions every element with class "abs" 20px to the left (and 0px from top) of the ul element.

What would you like to achieve? Your menu horizontally or vertically?

Horizontally: Use float:left or display:inline with a margin-left:20px;

Vertically: for a 20px margin-left:
http://jsbin.com/ediloh/17/edit

I first added margin:0px to delete the top and bottom margin of the ul element. Next I added a left margin of 20px to move it to the right.

alternative: put margin-left on the li-element instead. This will not move the circles

Comment: Thanks @Pepe I knew the alternative about using margin which you present in your Jsbin editor. I was just curious to know about the reason why positioning thing is not working here ?

Comment: By using position:absolute on your li-elements, you take them out of the normal page flow. 

This means that they do not have a relation with anything else but their first parent-object with a position-attribute. Here it is the ul-element with position:relative.

This relation can be giving a value by using top/bottom/right/left.

You used left:0px. If no top/bottom value is given, it'll use top:0px.

So each li-element as a relation with the ul-element:being positioned on left:20px, top0px. The li-elements do not have any relation between themselves, thus not push eachother down.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I see there is some confusion here. My ul elements are not `relative` positioned while there is a div with class rel which is relative positioned. If relative position is added to ul then I think your reasoning is right but here my div is relative positioned. Can you please check this one.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that div. Sorry. For your code, I suspect this is the proper way to put it: By absolute positioning the div.abs doesn't give its height to your div.rel (because it has broken out of the normal flow). Therefor the div.rel all have a height of 0px. The sum of all these heights, logically, also 0, making the divs seem collapsed. Easiest way to fix it is by putting a height to your div.rel:
http://jsbin.com/ediloh/20/edit


I think that is the answer you needed?

Answer (score 0):

The divs with `position:absolute` are taken out of the page flow, basically causing their parent divs to have no content at all (no content amounting to any width or height that is). So they will collapse.

Comment: If you say elements with `position:absolute` are taken out of page, then why won't list elements are getting rendered at start of body. My understanding is if their parent is relative positioned then they are moved w.r.t to its parent.

Comment: Checkout Point4 in http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score -1):

What outcome do you actually want.  You are fixing the div.abs to be indented by 20px inside its containing div.rel.

Could you give some idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Wing

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than answer to the question.

Comment: I wasnt at the time able to leave comments as I did not have enough points - at the time also had not quite figured out how Stackoverflow worked. Understand now. Was only trying to help